# Value in directive binding is correct but it's not returning true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm getting some strange behavior from a custom directive. If I pass in a value directly it seems to work but if I pass in a binding to a value it does not work. Also, the value when I console.log seems to be correct but it doesn't return true.

```
//directive
angular.module('tallllyApp')
  .directive('userColor', ['simpleLogin', '$timeout', function (simpleLogin, $timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        color: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        el.css('background', '#5DC472');
        console.log(attrs); //attrs.color shows 'Andrey'
        console.log(attrs.color); //displays nothing
        console.log(attrs.color === 'Andrey'); //false
      }
    };
  }]);

//html = {{profile.name}} does output 'Andrey'    
<section class="col user-tasks" user-color color="{{profile.name}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most possibly your issue could be with asynchronously assigned `profile.name`, by the time you run the directive the data might not have come back yet. So one technique you can apply is to wait till you get the data by registering a watch on the attribute (`attrs.$observe`) of on the scope property (`scope.$watch`), and cleanup the watch once you got the value.

Example:-

```
  link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        el.css('background', '#5DC472');

       //attrs.$observe('color', function(v){
        var unWatch = scope.$watch('color', function(v){ //Set up a watch
          if(v){ //Check if you got the value yet if so
            unWatch(); //clear the watch
            init(); //initialize directive
          }
        });

        function init(){
           console.log(attrs);
           console.log(scope.color); //attrs.color
           console.log(scope.color === 'Andrey');
        }
      }
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/30yAOO?p=preview)**

Comment: That's exactly correct. Man, it's tough to get this asynchronous stuff down. Any recommended reading for angular specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try binding the scope differently, like this?  (Though for me it worked both ways)

```
//directive
angular.module('tallllyApp')
  .directive('userColor', ['simpleLogin', '$timeout', function (simpleLogin, $timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        color: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        el.css('background', '#5DC472');
        console.log(scope.color); //should display 'Andrey'
      }
    };
  }]);

//html = {{profile.name}} does output 'Andrey'    
<section class="col user-tasks" user-color color="profile.name">
```

Comment: I did try this. It was definitely because of the asynchronous profile.name. As far as I understand, '=' is used when I need to run a method on the scope. I watched the egghead.com videos on it but they didn't cover my specific case.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are actually using your directive and data but typically you would just go ahead and insert the scope data directly into the template, and angular will automatically populate the data when the value loads.  If you need access to the value in your directive's link method then you'll definitely have to set up your own watcher.